# PHP: Array Function

Tags: php

I have a select-menu on my page, that lists the following system fonts in an array:

```
$default = array(
    'Arial'             => 'Arial',
    'Courier'           => 'Courier New',
    'Georgia'           => 'Georgia',
    'Helvetica'         => 'Helvetica',
    'Impact'            => 'Impact',
    'Palatino'          => 'Palatino',
    'Tahoma'            => 'Tahoma, Geneva',    
    'Times'             => 'Times New Roman',
    'Verdana'           => 'Verdana, Geneva'
);
```

When the user selects one of these fonts from the drop-down/select-menu, the font-face is output into the CSS head section of my site, like so:

```
p {font: 12px Arial;}
```

This works perfectly fine, but what I am hoping to do is change the CSS to also output fall-backs:

```
p {font: 12px Arial, san-serif;}
```

As I'm fairly new to PHP, using a comma and the fall-backs like the script below won't work and I was wondering how would I be able to add another font or fall-back to the array?

```
$default = array(
    'Arial, sans-serif'             => 'Arial',
    'Courier New, monospace'        => 'Courier New',
    'Georgia, serif'                => 'Georgia',
    'Helvetica, sans-serif'         => 'Helvetica',
    'Impact, sans-serif'            => 'Impact',
    'Palatino, serif'               => 'Palatino',
    'Times New Roman, serif'        => 'Times New Roman',
    'Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif'   => 'Verdana, Geneva'
);
```

Comment: What is the exact issue ? Do you get any error from PHP ? I have try your exact list and looks like working properly. Also, can you give as here, what is the selection option control result ? I mean what is the final output of your PHP Script

Comment: How are you actually using the `$default` array?

Comment: if you are trying to change font-family in css file you can rename your css file extension to .php and have variable instead of font-family like: {font-family:<?php echo $font;?>;}. Don't know is that what you are looking for but you can have default font and check in $_SESSION for example if font is not set than display default one

Answer (score 1):

In your options panel, use the following code:

```
// This is the value you retrieve from your database.
// Change it according to your code needs
$current_font_family = $db_options_result['font_family'];

$default = array(
    'Arial, sans-serif'             => 'Arial',
    'Courier New, monospace'        => 'Courier New',
    'Georgia, serif'                => 'Georgia',
    'Helvetica, sans-serif'         => 'Helvetica',
    'Impact, sans-serif'            => 'Impact',
    'Palatino, serif'               => 'Palatino',
    'Times New Roman, serif'        => 'Times New Roman',
    'Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif'   => 'Verdana, Geneva'
);

?>
<!-- Change the attributes of the select element according to your -->
<!-- code needs -->
<select name="fontFamily">
<?php
    foreach($default as $font_k => $font_v)
    {
?>
<!-- Remember to change the $current_font_family to your script variable name -->
<option value="<?php echo $font_k; ?>"<?php echo ($current_font_family == $font_k ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?>><?php echo $font_v; ?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
</select>
```

The above will generate in your admin panel an `HTML` select element that will look like the following:

```
<select name="fontFamily">
    <option value="Arial, sans-serif">Arial</option>
    <option value="Courier New, monospace">Courier New</option>
    <option value="Georgia, serif">Georgia</option>
    <option value="Helvetica, sans-serif">Helvetica</option>
    <option value="Impact, sans-serif">Impact</option>
    <option value="Palatino, serif">Palatino</option>
    <option value="Times New Roman, serif">Times New Roman</option>
    <option value="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif">Verdana, Geneva</option>
</select>
```

Then in your `CSS` use the following code:

```
<?php
    // This is the value you retrive from your database.
    // Change it according to your code needs

    $current_font_family = $db_options_result['font_family'];
?>
p {font: 12px <?php echo $current_font_family; ?>;}
```

Finally, in case you are using a `PHP` file as your `CSS` file for dynamic content don't forget to add this code on the very very top part of your file:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/css');
?>
```

Comment: Don't forget to sanitize the input if you are going to do it this way, it's better to do it more server-side (e.g. `<option value="arial">Arial</option>`, then change it with PHP: `array('arial' => 'Arial, sans-serif')` etc.).

Comment: That's mandatory. I jsut display here the way to do it. According to the platform used, may have already build in functionality for sanitization.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should exchange keys for values and it will do what you want, like this:

```
$default = array(
    'Arial'             =>    'Arial, sans-serif',
    'Courier New'       =>    'Courier New, monospace',
   ...
);
```

And that should do the trick. You normally search arrays by indexes and return values. So searching $default['Arial'] will yield "Arial, sans-serif". I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: This is now what he is looking for.

Comment: This is not what he asking for

Comment: @MerianosNikos What is OP actually looking for? This answer is how I read the question, so I'm kind of confused.

Comment: I suppose that he has a short kind of admin panel that allowing the end user to choose the font family to be used in the front end of his application. Then when the end user is choosing the font family, this value is stored in database, and then every time the front page is generated this option is used. Propably the issue comes from the admin panel in the select option list. This html element is generated in wrong way